# Autosys | Schedule Job every 30 minutes

Tags: scheduler, autosys

Autosys | JIL

i wish to run a job every 30 mins from 2100 till 0600 next day.

when i place the condition in jil for the job as below and try to upload

**start_times: "21:00,21:30,22:00,22:30,23:00,23:30,00:00,00:30,01:00,01:30,02:00,02:30,03:00,03:30,04:00,04:30,05:00,05:30,06:00"**

i get an error

**start_times exceeds 255 bytes.**

Comment: Is this correct?

run_window: "21:00-06:00"
start_mins: "00,30"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will work like Piyush said. I would probably put it like this:
 
        run_window: "21:00-06:00" 
        start_mins: "0,30"

If I remember correctly, you can also use the ":"
        start_mins: ":0,:30"
check if :30 works, if not, try like Piyush suggested

Answer (score 0):

run_window: "21:00-06:00"
start_mins: "0,30"

this was working , tested well